# Ubuntu Live CD: How to switch user on LiveCD to "root"

Tags: server, live-cd, sudo

I have created my customized live CD by following the instructions @ [Ubuntu Forum Thread 688872](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=688872)

The Live CD gets created fine and it is able to bootup as well. I see my customized setting in place.

I created the Live CD using Ubuntu 10.04 Server edition.

My issue is, when the system boots up with the live CD, it logs in automatically as "ubuntu" user. I want the system to login as "root". Because I will be running quite a few perl automation script off of the live CD and I need to have root privileges.

Now, i know the "sudo" way of doing it, But I am least bothered about the security aspect and want my system to switch to "root" user the moment it boots up.

Is there a hack to achieve the same?

**UPDATE**: If you cant resist to down vote my question, then please free to do so but do me a favor and let me know why you are down voting by dropping a comment.

Comment: I strongly advice to find an alternate method for deploying your perl scripts. You do know that you can add post-install scripts to your live cd? (`kickstart` I think it is called).

Comment: No, these are not post install scripts, I will running the SPECcpu test in fully automated way. these test and their iteration take 2-3 days to complete. This is a very big chunk of automation and could not be a part of "post kickstart stuff. Thanks for your time.

Comment: also, what's up with the down vote, what is wrong with the question, I really feeling that stackexchange should make comments mandatory while down voting someone's questions...

Comment: Ach @dheeraj someone will come along and upvote. I see a tendency for increased downvotes when someone asks to do anything about sudo/root. Don't bother with it since we can't stop it ;)

Comment: Would it be an option to put those scripts in cron? Or to make the user `ubuntu` a sudo account with no password just for the time to run these scripts? I looked around for about an hour but gave up on setting the custom live cd to use root. It looks to much of a hassle. Setting things up post-install is probably easier.

Comment: @Rinzwind,I am thinking of putting my scripts in rc.local and then run them with "sudo". If not then run them via sudo in Cron. I haven't yet tried either of these. I will do the testing and will update this thread regarding which approach is working fine. Thanks for your time and cron suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

The live CD will forget everything you did during your session, so I'd recommend booting from a USB key with a persistent session. Root has no password in live session, so in the CLI, if you do `sudo su`, it'll just go to root, and not ask for a password. You could easily make a bash script to go to root and then run your perl scripts.

By default root will timeout after 15 minutes, but you can change that, see [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudoTimeout).

Comment: yeah, USB is not an option as i will be mounting my ISO via Light out console of the server programatically. Thanks for your time and the hint regarding how to increase root timeout.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... not sure if this exactly relates, but as I described in [How is ubuntu live user graphical session (startx) started up in a LiveCD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/336272/how-is-ubuntu-live-user-graphical-session-startx-started-up-in-a-livecd) - if I start with a Mini remix (which ends with text/console login for the live user `ubuntu`); and then I configure startup of X (or the desktop environment) through `/etc/rc.local` - then the desktop environment is seemingly started under the `root` user. Unfortunately, I do not know how to switch to the `root` user already at login, so that the text mode console starts up as `root` as well...