# How is ubuntu live user graphical session (startx) started up in a LiveCD?

Tags: boot, live-cd, live-environment

I am trying to build a custom ISO, using `ubuntu-builder`. I've taken a 12.40 mini remix ISO as a starting point. Here is my specific example - however, I'm interested in principle how the process goes (so I can apply that to other DE/WM).

when I run a new ISO, built directly from the mini remix starting ISO, all is as expected - I can run the new ISO in a virtual machine, and the boot process terminates with text-only prompt for the live `ubuntu` user.

Now, I try to install LXDE (there is an entry for it in `ubuntu-builder`, apparently it installs `lxde-core` and X dependencies; and I manually have to install `lxterminal`, and as icons are missing, probably `lxde-icon-theme` as well). I have to also manually install `xinit`, so I have `startx`. But this, by itself, doesn't do much: if I boot this customized ISO in a virtual machine, the exact same thing happens as with the "original" ISO - boot process completes with a text mode prompt for `ubuntu` live user.

If I now type `startx` at this prompt, then LXDE starts (running `startlxde` at this prompt will complain about X), such that when you start `lxterminal` from that desktop, it is started under the live `ubuntu` user.

---

In [LiveCDCustomization - Boot init](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization#Boot_init), it is mentioned:

> Boot init
>   You have to edit the files in edit/usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/casper-bottom/* For example you can change the hostname or the livecd user.

... but I don't exactly understand what is exactly being ran by what there. The `ubuntu-builder` unpacks these files under `/home/ubuntu-builder/FileSystem/usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/casper-bottom/` - but as far as I can see, most of these just run some inline `sed` commands, I cannot see much executive commands there?

Still, I tried to copy one of the scripts there as a new script, `51startx`, which in the executable section has:

```
log_begin_msg "$DESCRIPTION"

chroot /root startx
chroot /root startlxde

log_end_msg
```

This does absolutely nothing - again, after boot, I get the usual text prompt `ubuntu@ubuntu:~$`.

---

Then I found [Modify: Startx automatically, add apt, etc - backtrack-linux.org](http://www.backtrack-linux.org/forums/showthread.php?t=40457):

> To have a graphical login, just install gdm and run it in startup:
>
> ```
> aptitude update
> aptitude install gdm
> ```
>
> Then, edit /etc/rc.local, and add a line BEFORE "exit 0" like this:
>
> ```
> service gdm start
> ```
>
> This is not the best way, but run! . This must work running "update-rc.d gdm defaults", but this way fail.

And indeed - I added:

```
startx
startlxde
```

... to `/etc/rc.local` - and this indeed does boot, and start LXDE automatically - however, when I run `lxterminal`, it is under user `root` - not under the live user `ubuntu`!

---

So, what should I do, so that I can start (any) X and/or any desktop environment automatically at boot under the live `ubuntu` user?

Note that in this case, I would **not** like to use an additional desktop manager (e.g. `gdm`) nor a corresponding greeter - but it would be good to know, if a solution for automatically starting up X would also work for a desktop manager or a greeter.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I think I got somewhere - but still don't quite get it, so a proper answer would be appreciated :)

But, basically: the boot process starts, somewhere in there the `init` process run, and the kernel loads - but also, some startup scripts run. These scripts are part of `initramfs`, from within the booting kernel they are referred to as `/scripts/...` - however, in the unpacked file system of `ubuntu-builder` they would be in `./FileSystem/usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/`. Eventually - in a typical install - this would end up with loading the given Display Manager (DM), which "[presents the user with a login screen which prompts for a username and password](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_display_manager_%28program_type%29)"; where apparently one design of such a screen in a DM is known as a *greeter*. Once the login has been performed in the DM greeter, then control is passed onto the Desktop Environment/Window Manager (DE/WM). I'm still not clear who/what starts the DM in the first place; but if it is started, I guess the DM afterwards is the starter of the DE/WM (depending on login authentication and settings). Or:

```
(boot start) --> initramfs --> scripts --> (kernel?) --> DM --> (login) --> DE+WM --> (boot completion)
```

I still cannot tell the difference between the DE and WM properly, but for example, `LXDE` is apparently a DE (as per the name); and typically it is used with `openbox` as a WM. So, in other words, what I want here is to skip the DM, and go directly to DE/WM as the live `ubuntu` user.

Back to the boot scripts - particularly, the `init-bottom` and `casper-bottom` are visible in the boot log messages - which are also available in the file `/var/log/boot.log`, once the ISO finishes booting and we can use `less`. Particularly interesting are these scripts:

```
$ sudo grep -ri "Adding live" ./FileSystem/usr/share/initramfs-tools/
./FileSystem/usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/casper-bottom/25adduser:DESCRIPTION="Adding live session user..."

$ sudo grep -ri dm ./FileSystem/usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/ | grep 'if \['
(./FileSystem/usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/casper-bottom/15autologin)
15autologin:if [ -d /root/etc/gdm ]; then
15autologin:if [ -f /root/etc/kde4/kdm/kdmrc ]; then
15autologin:if [ -f /root/etc/lxdm/lxdm.conf ]; then
15autologin:if [ -f /root/etc/xdg/lubuntu/lxdm/lxdm.conf ]; then
15autologin:if [ -d /root/etc/lightdm ]; then
```

So, the `autologin` script basically *counts on* a Display Manager (DM) being *already* installed (in the CD image) - and simply searches for possible config files thereof, and replaces inplace using `sed`, such that the particular DM performs an automatic login, once it is started (by whatever usually starts it). On the other hand, the `adduser` script creates the live user `ubuntu` *from scratch* during boot - and as such, there are no files we could apriori edit and store on the CD image.

The good thing, however, is that these scripts definitely run before `/etc/rc.local` runs, which runs before the `bash` terminal is ultimately started at end of boot. So what I've done, is used the `/etc/rc.local` file to "inject" an `X` startup sequence in `~/.bashrc` of the `ubuntu` user:

```
$ tail -n 15 ./FileSystem/etc/rc.local 
#
# By default this script does nothing.

#sed -i 's/console/anyone/' /etc/X11/Xwrapper.config
#su - ubuntu -c "touch /home/ubuntu/.Xauthority"
#su - ubuntu -c startx
#sed -i 's/anyone/console/' /etc/X11/Xwrapper.config

echo ls -la /home/ubuntu
ls -la /home/ubuntu
# echo startx >> /home/ubuntu/.bashrc # this gives error "Server is already active for display 0"
echo 'if [ -z "$DISPLAY" ] && [ $(tty) == /dev/tty1 ]; then startx ; fi' >> /home/ubuntu/.bashrc
ls -la /home/ubuntu

exit 0
```

So, in brief:

- Trying to mess with `.Xauthority` will not help here; the failure will be "`X: user not authorized to run the X server, aborting.`"
- Just pushing `startx` into `.bashrc` will not help here; the failure (after a long black screen) will be "`Server is already active for display 0`"
- However, `startx` within an `if [ ... ]` check will succeed (*but I don't understand why would a simple `if []` make a difference?*)!

In my case, that `startx` command starts both `LXDE` and `openbox`, so both the DE and the WM (*how and why, I still don't understand*). So all looks good now - except for icons, and that I have [no shutdown, suspend, hibernate and reboot options](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1148545). But at least the immediate problem in my OP is solved. However, I'd still appreciate a more proper description of what goes on here.

---

Below are some links/quotes which I found useful:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Display_Manager_%28implementation%29

> XDM (in full, the X Window Display Manager) is the default display manager for the X Window System. It is a bare-bones X display manager. It was introduced with X11 Release 3 in October 1988, to support the standalone X terminals that were just coming onto the market.

- [comp.os.linux.x: Re: how to autologin in xdm?](http://linux.derkeiler.com/Newsgroups/comp.os.linux.x/2003-07/0373.html) (via [[all variants] Autologin with XDM, minimal XFCE install](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=817726))

> What I don't get is why you want to use xdm when you aren't going to use
>   it? I mean, having xdm auto-login is precisely the opposite of what it was
>   designed to do: Give you a graphical login prompt.
>
> Use runlevel 3 and add 'su -  -c startx' to
>   /etc/init.d/rc.local or (if using inittab) change
>   "x:5:respawn:/etc/X11/prefdm -nodaemon" to "x:5:respawn:su - 
>   -c startx".

- [since we have no /etc/inittab (linuxquestions.org)](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/ubuntu-63/since-we-have-no-etc-inittab-506281/)

> If you create your own /etc/inittab file, Ubuntu will honour it.
>
> To change your runlevels the Ubuntu way look in /etc/init.d/ which contains startup scripts. Then look in /etc/rc#.d/ which contains symlinks to scripts in /etc/init.d/. The name of the symlinks determines what will be started/stopped and in what order.

- [[SOLVED] "Server is already active for display 0" in Terminals / Arch Linux Forums](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=88699)

> In bashrc try something like
>
> ```
> [ -z "$DISPLAY" ] && startx && {sleep 5; DISPLAY=0:0 setsid Guake; }
> ```

- [Debian User Forums • View topic - auto login and startx without a display manager - lenny](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?t=29333)

> for automatic startx
>   edit .bash_profile (or other file that gets run when you login) and add
>
> ```
> if [ -z "$DISPLAY" ] && [ $(tty) == /dev/tty1 ]; then
>    startx
> fi
> ```